# How do i bypass "Invalid nal size" on FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to render a video with hardcoded subtitle. But I received this messages:

```
[h264 @ 0x56048835b000] Invalid nal size 13504
[h264 @ 0x56048835b000] Error splitting the input into NAL units.
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x560488313ee0] stream 1, offset 0x67093f: partial file
http://xxx/xxx/raw/20200618095327.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x560488313ee0] stream 0, offset 0x670aaa: partial file
http://xxx/xxx/raw/20200618095327.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x560488313ee0] stream 1, offset 0x670c51: partial file
http://xxx/xxx/raw/20200618095327.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
frame=  500 fps=3.2 q=29.0 size=    6433kB time=00:00:16.60 bitrate=3174.2kbits/s speed=0.105x
```

The video "seems" to be ok, because I can actually read it both in VLC / Quicktime and in Chrome.

Is there anyway to circumvent this error? Where would this come from?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser! Can you perhaps indicate what you've tried so far to resolve/research this issue? Did you lookup what `Invalida nal size` means in ffmpeg? If others had similar issues? If you did look into that, why were the solutions you found not helpful?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke, The message seems to indicate that the file is corrupted. As I mentionned in post, I have tried the video on multiple player on my computer, and it plays well. I've tried to change the output file format (doesn't make sense but why not?) and the result is the same.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you've tried so far? Also links to where you found that the file is corrupted when this error comes up. Perhaps you can re-encode your video first with ffmpeg before adding hardcoded subtitles? See e.g.: https://superuser.com/questions/1056599/ffmpeg-re-encode-a-video-keeping-settings-similar